# Insert word into specific position in a list

Tags: python, list

Sorry if the title isn't descriptive enough. Basically, I have a list like

```
["The house is red.", "Yes it is red.", "Very very red."]
```

and I'd like to insert the word `"super"` before the first character, between the middle characters and after the last character of each string. So I would have something like this for the first element:

```
["superThe houssupere is red.super",...]
```

How would I do this? I know with strings I could use add the `"super"` string to the beginning of my string then use `len()` to go to the middle of the string and add `"super"`. Is there a way to get this to work with a list or should I try a different approach?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried until now, and what doesn't work (complete error message, or the result you obtained compared to what you expected). Then we can help you solve your problem!

Comment: `['super{0}super{1}super'.format(i[:len(i)//2], i[len(i)//2:]) for i in li]`?. This seems like na... odd request though.

Comment: You already know how to do this with a single string.  Let's assume you have a function make_super_string(x).  Try map(make_super_string, the_list).  In general, you can iterate through the list changing each entry, or you can create a new list (and optionally just swap it out by assigning it to the same variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method used here is to iterate through the original list, splitting each item into two halves and building the final item string using `.format` before appending it into a new list.

```
orig_list = ["The house is red.", "Yes it is red.", "Very very red."]
new_list = []
word = 'super'

for item in orig_list:
    first_half = item[:len(item) // 2]
    second_half = item[len(item) // 2:]
    item = '{}{}{}{}{}'.format(word, first_half, word, second_half, word)
    new_list.append(item)
```